# Passing multiple USSD commands in a single call

Tags: ussd

Say you have a USSD service which has the following structure:

`Main menu -> *123#`

`Menu Item 1 -> Press 1 from main menu`

`Menu Item 2 -> Press 2 from main menu`

Is there any way to dial a single command to go straight to Menu Item 1, for example `*123#1` as opposed to dialing `*123#`, then waiting for the Menu, THEN selecting 1?

Hope the question is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to handle USSD auto dialing in your application.
For example a user should be able to dial *123*2# to go straight to menu item 2. 
Check the SMSGH USSD Framework for implementation details [here](https://github.com/smsgh/smsgh-ussd-framework-java/blob/master/ussd-framework/src/main/java/com/smsgh/ussd/framework/Ussd.java) from line 69.

Comment: hmm, i see. But the problem is, i want to use an already existing USSD service(not developed by me) in this manner in my application

Comment: but looking at that code, its obvious that it depends on the implementation. Thanks

Comment: This depends on the telco. Many prevent going to sub-menus for security reasons